# GitHub keeps prompting me to choose an account

Tags: git, github

[image: git_prompt]

As shown in the image, GitHub keeps asking me to select an account (duplicates?) even though both accounts have the same name. I have only added one account in GitHub, but for the past few days, I have been getting this pop-up to choose an account.

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't happen on the website?

Comment: also, what happens if you delete and reinstall the Github app on your computer?

Comment: @Mark this doesn't happens on website. it happens on git cli. someone edited the question and changed it to github.com

Comment: how odd! I think deleting and reinstalling it is the first port of call, to rule out weird installation issues on your pc

Comment: @Mark reinstalling along with removing all values with 'github' from windows credentials seems to have worked for me :)

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/1325#issuecomment-1631642589

Comment: This randomly started happening to me today.  working as normal this morning then started prompting for user or token.  Not in browser, it happens using git-fork VS code nor VS2022

Answer (score 1):

This command solve my issues.

```
git config --global --unset-all credential.helper
```